# AHK simulate holding key while physical holding key down

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I am having trouble with an autohotkey script. What I want it to do is by physically holding down A on my keyboard I would like the script to tap mouse button4 and then hold down 1 for as long as I am holding down A for. When I release A I would like the script to release 1 as well.
My bad attempt at the script is

```
a::
send {Xbutton1}
sleep 10
Send {1 down}
While GetKeyState(a, "p")
    Sleep 10
Send {1 up}
Return
```

The problem I am having is that the script is not holding down 1 as I am holding down A. Does anyone talented in ahk know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a::
send {Xbutton1}
sleep 10
While GetKeyState("a", "p")
 {
 Send {1 down}
 Sleep 10
 }
Send {1 up}
Return
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I sometimes put comments if code is longer but this is all self explanatory. The original question almost had it, there were just a couple little mistakes.

Comment: Hmm there is still something wrong. The 1 key is still not being held down by the macro. The first part of the macro (sending xbutton1) seems to be the only thing that is working.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. Instead of having "a" as the hotkey I had it changed to 1. Since 1 was the same key that was being pressed in the script I was having problems. So what I needed to do was add $1:: to the first line.